# Conditionnaly counting the number of occurences in a column

Tags: excel-formula

I have a table that contains a list of people. Every person has a role (Boss, Worker, Aid) and a duty (Cleaning kitchen, Take out trash, Washing up, Day-off).

I have an other table that lists the possibles duties. The duty is refered to by a code (A,B,C,D) and in the third column there can be a 'X' that mean "this duty is to be counted" or no text at all that mean "this duty is not to be counted". A Day-off typically doesn't have an 'X'.

I want to be able to see how many Bosses, Workers and Aids are working according to what duty they have been given.

I've tried using VLOOKUP but it doesn't give me an array as an output. I tried a combination of INDEX and MATCH but I can't make it work. I'v tried using SUMPRODUCT and a combination of SUM and IF. I think I might be misunderstanding how to use array function or at least how to use the result in another formula.

[A view of my Worksheet to get better visualization](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H4ir7.png)

Thank you in advance for you help, I'm sure the answer is simple but I can't think of it !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Try using **COUNTIFS**.

Presume you have **named** the following ranges:

- **Person**: `B12:B20`
- **Role**: `C12:C20`
- **Duty_Code**: `D12:D20`

For working bosses: `=COUNTIFS(Role,"Boss",Duty_code,"<>D")`

For working workers: `=COUNTIFS(Role,"Worker",Duty_code,"<>D")`

For working aids: `=COUNTIFS(Role,"Aid",Duty_code,"<>D")`

A suggestion would be putting the criteria i.e. `Boss`, `Worker` and `Aid` in Cell `C3`, `C4` and `C5` on your example worksheet, and replace the hard-coded criteria in the above formulas with the corresponding cell address.

[image: COUNTIFS]